# Ubuntu 16.04 Workspace switcher fails with multiple, different sized, monitors

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Running 16.04 with Unity my primary display is a 27" 4K HDMI at 3840x2160. I've set my Workspaces to 8x1, all works as expected.

Adding a second 23" display with DisplayPort at 1920x1200 causes Workspaces and the Switcher to do nothing- no Workspaces, no Switching.

dconf shows 8x1, Compiz Settings shows Desktop Wall & Viewport Switcher enabled.

What am I missing?